# SFSafariViewController's navigation bar color is not solid

Tags: ios, swift3, sfsafariviewcontroller, tintcolor, translucency

I have a view controller and I am opening SFSafariViewController from one view controller to open a link. I have given a tink color to SFSafariViewController. But tint color which I am giving is not the same color which I have given to it. I have tried to off the translucency but still, that doesn't effect.

Below is the code which I am using to give the tint color to SFSafariViewController:

```
func loadUrlinWebView(urlString: String?) {
    guard let urlVal = urlString else {
        return
    }
    let url = URL(string: urlVal)
    let controller = SFSafariViewController(url: url!)
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        controller.preferredBarTintColor = UIColor(red: 234.0 / 255.0, green: 108.0 / 255.0, blue: 19.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        controller.preferredControlTintColor = .white
    } else {
        controller.view.tintColor = UIColor(red: 234.0 / 255.0, green: 108.0 / 255.0, blue: 19.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    (controller.view.subviews[0].subviews[0] as? UINavigationBar)?.barTintColor = UIColor.tracePrimaryColor
    (controller.view.subviews[0].subviews[0] as? UINavigationBar)?.isTranslucent = false
    (controller.view.subviews[0].subviews[1] as? UIToolbar)?.barTintColor = UIColor.tracePrimaryColor
    (controller.view.subviews[0].subviews[1] as? UIToolbar)?.isTranslucent = false

    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    controller.delegate = self
}
```

The actual color which I am setting is : `UIColor(red: 234.0 / 255.0, green: 108.0 / 255.0, blue: 19.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)`
And the color which I can see on SFSafariViewController's navigation bar is `UIColor(red: 233.0 / 255.0, green: 116.0 / 255.0, blue: 47.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)`.

Using above code I have received the actual color `( UIColor(red: 234.0 / 255.0, green: 108.0 / 255.0, blue: 19.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0))` on SFSafariViewController's navigation bar for the fraction of seconds then again that color changed to `(UIColor(red: 233.0 / 255.0, green: 116.0 / 255.0, blue: 47.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0))`. I don't know why this is the behaviour.

Please help me in this.

Comment: `SFSafariViewController` is not meant to be customized this way. If you want to make a custom web view for your content, use `WKWebView`.

Comment: But using above code I can see the actual color for the fraction of seconds but after that, it changed to another color. I don't understand the reason behind it.

Comment: At the point of initializing, the view structure in `SFSafariViewController` is different and it will recreate its toolbar and navigation bar after some time, that's why you experience a short blink in color change.

Comment: Okay. So the only way is to use WKWebView?

Comment: Yes, I'd recommend to use `WKWebView` for this.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your reply @the4kman